# ComboBox open on mouse over event and close after mouse moves off it - in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Idea is to have a ComboBox open - when mouse cursor moves over it, without having to click on it, and when mouse moves off it for it to close back down.

Code below seem to be opening it, but with caveats:

a) code keeps firing the Alt + Arrow Down while you are thinking what list item to pick - want it to do it just to open the ComboBox and then stop,

b) once you pick the item, it fires Alt + Arrow Down on a new active cell, which is not the intent. And that new cell prevents ComboBox from opening on the next mouse over.
(*I also have another code, which once list item is picked is finding and selecting corresponding cell in A column)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ComboBox1.Activate
    SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

Comment: consider having a plain list with your selections, which is not visible until you mouse over a text box.  The list is at the same xy as the text box.  Then on the list use the exit event to hide the list.  When there is a click on the list box value the text box with the selection.

Comment: I'll consider more details on what are you proposing. @igittr

Comment: See class solution for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Some users might find move over solution annoying -- but would be interesting to test it out, if it comes along.

Went with a click anywhere on the Box meantime, as it is better than having to click on an arrow icon only.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus() 'when clicked on anywhere - not just arrow icon, opens
    SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

on your form create TextBox1 and ListBox1.
Paste this example code into your form.

```
Dim autoList As CautoOpenList
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
        'optional capture of keyboard action to leave textbox
        autoList.flipFields True
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
        ' optional capture of keyboard action to leave listbox
        autoList.flipFields False
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        ListBox1.List = split("A,B,C,D,E,F",",") ' value your listbox with your values
        Set autoList = New CautoOpenList
        autoList.Form = Me
        autoList.LiBox = ListBox1  ' your listbox name
        autoList.TxBox = TextBox1  'your textbox name
        
        End Sub
```

Then include this class module into your workbook with the name CautoOpenList.

```
Option Explicit
Private taboff As Boolean, aForm As MSForms.UserForm
Private WithEvents LiBx As MSForms.ListBox
Private WithEvents TxBx As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents Labl As MSForms.Label
Public Property Let LiBox(obj As Object)
        Set LiBx = obj
        LiBx.Visible = False
End Property
Public Property Let TxBox(obj As Object)
        ' connect listbox before connecting text box
        Set TxBx = obj
        With LiBx
                .Top = TxBx.Top - 5
                .Left = TxBx.Left - 5
        End With
        'label necessary to capture mouse off-to-right when listbox has scroll bar
        Set Labl = aForm.Controls.Add("forms.label.1", "Labl", False)
        With Labl
                .Top = LiBx.Top
                .Height = LiBx.Height
                .Width = 5
                .Left = LiBx.Left + LiBx.Width
        End With
End Property
Public Property Let Form(obj As Object)
        ' connect from to class before connecting the textbox
        Set aForm = obj
End Property
Private Sub LiBx_Click()
        TxBx.Text = LiBx.Text
End Sub
Private Sub Labl_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        flipFields False
        Debug.Print "MM"
End Sub

Private Sub LiBx_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        With LiBx
                If X < 4 Then  ' Or X > nRightBound Then
                        flipFields False
                 End If
                If Y < 4 Or Y > .Height - 6 Then
                       flipFields False
                End If
        End With
End Sub

Private Sub TxBx_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        With LiBx
                flipFields True
        End With
End Sub
Public Sub flipFields(b As Boolean)
        LiBx.Visible = b
        Labl.Visible = b
        TxBx.Visible = Not b
        DoEvents
End Sub
```